# Where could I find UML diagrams of an open source project?

Tags: open-source, uml, project, use-case, sequence-diagram

I'm going to start a project for my software engineering course, and I have to do a relatively hard one, something like a browser. Of course I'm not going to build a complete browser from scratch in 4 monthes, but in the first phases I have to give my analyze output to the TA. This includes use case diagrams, sequence diagrams and other UML diagrams.
since I've never done a project like this, I'm looking for diagrams of an open source project which I can get some ideas from them. Where could I find such open source projects that give me these diagrams?

Comment: i dont think this question should be downvoted

Comment: You're probably best off looking at open source UML tools; most open source projects don't use UML, but the tools are more likely to eat their own dogfood.

Comment: @Pete Do you know why most open source projects don't use UML? and do you know any open source UML tool that uses itself?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to learn how the UML of a project is laid out, then one thing you could do is checkout any open source project written C#/Java/VB, import it to this tool called [Altova Umodel](http://www.altova.com/umodel/uml-reverse-engineering.html). They have free trial version but the software itself is sold commercially.

Hope that helps..

Comment: thanks! that seems a nice tool, but I think I'll have some challenges by using it for determining what element belongs to which concept! I'll do that if I don't find a prepared one!